# No users in Firebase Audiences when the event count is 0

Tags: firebase, analytics, firebase-analytics

I have several Audiences defined in Firebase, however in some of them I haven't registered a single user still, while in others I have thousands registered.

My only guess is that it happens because I have an event condition defined with `count = 0`.

For example, I have these two Audiences:

- Users that failed to login but then succeed.
- Users that failed to login and never succeed.

For that, I have two events defined: login_succeed and login_failed.

The first Audience is defined as follows:

[image: Failed and Succeed Conditions]

The second Audience is defined as follows:

[image: Failed and NEVER Succeed Conditions]

The issue: There are no users registered for the second condition, and we know that there are many users that can't login in the app.

I have other Audiences that define `count = 0` as well and all of them are empty.

Is this a Firebase issue? That `count = 0` in an event is not supported when defining Audiences?

Thanks for your help!

Comment: I find this audience definition a bit strange. Once a user becomes an audience, they will be in that audience forever. It means that you will probably have overlapping numbers of both audiences in case of the second filter works. Regarding the count = 0, I am not sure why it is happening. I am guessing it is because you did not log login_successful event when users failed to login so basically there is no audience evaluated.

Comment: > Once a user becomes an audience, they will be in that audience forever.

I didn't know that, then makes all sense that the audiences with a particular event count = 0 will never work because as soon as that user has an event will have to be removed from the audience, which won't be possible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Currently, an audience is only counted when there is an event that satisfies the audience filter. If there is no event login_successful logged yet, there will be no audience. The number of users will be correct once there is audience count > 0 so currently, there is only positive case.

Answer (score 1):

An audience filter is only evaluated when there is an event *or user property* that appears somewhere in that filter.

See if this work-around works for you: define your audience with a single filter: myEvent event count = 0 OR first open time < (some really early date)

So create a filter that has the event count = 0, but use the OR button to add another condition to the same filter that checks the user property "first open time" to be less than some long-ago date that's earlier than your app was released.  Maybe January 1st, 2010 or something.  First open time is a user property that's set when your app is first opened and appears in every event bundle after that so it should always trigger your audience to be evaluated.

Make sure you are checking the user property "first open time", not the event "first open".  :)

Comment: BTW, an audience filter for event count = 0 is of limited value anyway.  The reason is that once a user satisfies a filter they will always be considered to satisfy that filter even if they stop satisfying it.  That's just the way audiences work: once you're in it, you're always in it.

Comment: So an event count = 0 audience really measures which users hadn't logged that event *by the first time they opened the app after the audience was created*.  Users that already logged the event will never be in because they can't un-log it, and users that didn't will still be in the audience even after logging the event.

Comment: It looks like my workaround suggested above won't work.  The event count part of the filter and the user property part of the filter are treated as two separate filters so the user property part is evaluated but the event count part still isn't.

Answer (score 1):

**If your goal is for Notifications**

You need to check opposite, create the audience with the =1 OR >1 and select the "Does not include all of". Please check the attached screenshot for better understanding.

[Reference from](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47437923/firebase-audience-targeting-on-count-operators/47438599#47438599)

**Create Audience**:
[image]

**Condition in Notification**
[image]