# Firebase Audience Targeting on Count Operators

Tags: firebase, firebase-analytics, firebase-console

I use Firebase Analytics & Audiences for event tracking & push notification campaigns. I want to target my app's users that did not have an `in_app_purchase` across their entire lifetime.

I created the following tests in the Firebase Analytics Audiences dashboard, but could unfortunately not save & create the audiences:

- Test 2 below does not work with `in_app_purchase Count < 1`.

  [image: screenshot]
- Test 3 does not work with `in_app_purchase Count = 0`.

  [image: screenshot]

I assume I am not the only one that want to grow their buyer segment. So, I am curious how one would be able to create this audience in Firebase (and target them thereafter with a push notification)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Firebase Analytics includes a default audience of "Purchasers" which can then be used in reverse (using "does not include all of") to compose a message to users that are not part of this audience:

[image: FCM compose screenshot]